# How to push array into Anypoint Monitoring custom metrics?

Tags: mule, metrics, anypoint-platform

I need to push an JSON array information into custom dashboard table.

```
[
 {
 api_name: "abc_api",
  owner: "avish"
},
{
api_name: "xyz_api",
owner: "avesh"
},
etc...
]
```

I need to push the info into a table with 2 column like API_NAME and API_OWNER.

Please let me know if this can be possible with 'anypoint custom metric' connector or do we have any option in mulesoft ?

Comment: Have you read the documentation https://docs.mulesoft.com/monitoring/anypoint-custom-metrics-connector? Have you tried something?

Comment: yes, i can push one metric at a time but my requirement is to push an array of objects into a table. is it possible as i mentioned in question ?

Answer (score 0):

Values for measurements [have to be numerical.](https://docs.mulesoft.com/monitoring/anypoint-custom-metrics-connector#configure-custom-metrics-values-using-anypoint-studio) It doesn't seem that the data that you want to push is compatible with custom metrics.